# I want to delete the selected record from database

Tags: php, codeigniter

I have two form views: form and controller.

Below are the codes which I want to delete the selected record from database using codeginiter.

Please check why `code.controller` form is not working.

**view Form**

```
function deleteCustEntry(id){
    var answer = confirm("Are you sure you want to move in trash?")

    if (answer){
    $.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: '<?php echo base_url();?>manager/deletecust/',          
    data: { manager_id: id, status : 'trash'},
    }
}
```

**Controller form**

```
public function deletecust() {

    $manager_id = $this->input->post('manager_id');

    $status = $this->input->post('status');

    $result = 0;


    if($status == 'trash') {

        $data = array(
            'isTrash' => 1
        );

        $this->db->where('id', $manager_id);

        $this->db->update('manager', $data); 

        $result = 1;

    } elseif ($status == 'delete'){

        $this->db->delete('manager', array('id' => $manager_id));

        if ($this->db->affected_rows() > 0) {
            $result = 1;
        }
    }

    echo $result;

    flush();
}
```

Comment: Why you write your query in controller? This is poor use on MVC!!

Comment: please help me how to do

Comment: @user3141880 you should move the business logics to your model. If you follow your coding pattern, you will ultimately end up with what we call 'thin model, fat controller' apps which can be troublesome to debug and scale up. This is a big subject, and not in context to your question either. You should google these things..

Comment: thanks .please help me in this code also

Answer (score 1):

do you want to delete the record from the table or change the status of the record. As status : 'trash' this will always change the status of isTrash. Provide more info.